# DocuSign API - Email Notification Settings

Tags: docusignapi

I'm successfully sending envelopes via the DocuSign eSignature API and have a question about the emails that are sent as part of the signing process. When a request is sent I'm receiving the following emails (using the Sandbox environment):

1. email to each recipient from dse_demo@docusign.net with a reply to of my name/email address
2. email to me when each recipient clicks the link to view the agreement to sign (e.g. "John Smith viewed Acme Co Customer Agreement")
3. email to me (and each recipient) when agreement has been completed.

I'm trying to understand what options are available for each of these as far as:

1. enabling/disabling each of these emails
2. changing the email address used for each of these (and if this can be done via the API)

Appreciate any insights into whether and how I can make any changes to these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion emails can be enabled/disabled in the settings for your DocuSign account. This can be found in: Settings > Signing Settings > Envelope Delivery. You can also enable/disable the "envelope viewed" notification emails and completion emails for both the sender and signer in: Settings > Email Preferences.

Which language are you integrating the API with? In C# you can change the email when adding the envelope recipient in the envelope definition e.g.

```
private static EnvelopeDefinition MakeEnvelope(string recipientEmail)
{
    recipientEmail = "recipientEmail@email.com"

byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("filePath");

Document doc1 = new Document();
string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
doc1.DocumentBase64 = b64;
doc1.Name = "Document Name";
doc1.FileExtension = "pdf";
doc1.DocumentId = "1";

env.Documents = new List<Document> { doc1 };

Text textTab = new Text
{
    DocumentId = "1",
    PageNumber = "1",
    XPosition = "168",
    YPosition = "513",
    Height = "17",
    Width = "369",
    Value = "envelopeTabText",
    Locked = "true"
};

SignHere signer1signhere = new SignHere
{
    DocumentId = "1",
    PageNumber = "1",
    XPosition = "128",
    YPosition = "775"
};

**Signer signer1 = new Signer
{
    Email = recipientEmail,
    Name = "customerName",
    RecipientId = "1",
    RoutingOrder = "1"
};**

Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs
{
    TextTabs = new List<Text> { textTab },
    SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signer1signhere }
};
signer1.Tabs = signer1Tabs;

Recipients recipients = new Recipients
{
    Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1 }
};

env.Recipients = recipients;
env.Status = "sent";
return env;
}
```